# How to create separate buffers from the ouput of grep?

Tags: buffers, grep

Is there any way to create separate buffers for each file grep locates when running something like

grep 'blabla' *.c

Comment: First, you can isolate the file names with `grep -l 'blabla' *.c`. Then, to get the file list in Emacs (i.e. the output of the command) you can use `shell-command-to-string`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the `grep` command through `M-x`, then `M-g M-n` will automatically open a buffer and place the point at the position where grep found the match.